# Create docker image from different branch in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm working with GitHub actions.
My default branch is "main".
I creating hotfix/** branch from a tags which is production tags and always behind main.
Now i want to open pull request and i need to create docker image from the branch hotfix/** and not from "main".
I dont know the branch name everytime, but it starts with hotfix/**.

How can i do that?
I'm tried to use checkoutv3 but with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To create a Docker image from a branch starting with "hotfix/**" in GitHub Actions:

1. Use the `if` condition to check if the branch name starts with "hotfix/":

   ```yaml
   jobs:
     build:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest
       steps:
         - name: Checkout code
           uses: actions/checkout@v2
           with:
             ref: ${{ github.ref }}
         - name: Build and push Docker image
           if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/hotfix/')
           run: |
             # Build and push Docker image from the hotfix branch
             # Replace this with your Docker image build and push commands
   ```
2. Replace the placeholder comment with the commands to build and push the Docker image.

This will ensure that the Docker image is built and pushed only when a branch with the name starting with "hotfix/" triggers the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
     steps:
  - name: Checkout hotfix branch
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**